# How many ways can 5 couples (4 American + 1 Indian) be arranged in a circle given the conditions?

Tags: probability

> *One Indian* and *four American* men and their wives are to be seated randomly around a circular table. Then the conditional probability that the Indian man is seated adjacent to his wife given that each American man is seated adjacent to his wife, is ?

*Here's what I did*:

Considering that the American couples will sit together, we'll consider them as a single unit. So we no longer have 10 people; We only have 4 units and 2 Indian people.

*Calculating the total probability:*
The 4 units can be placed on the round table in $ 3! $ ways. In between those units we got 4 gaps. We select two gaps in $ ^4C_2 $ ways and place the Indian couple there (if they don't sit together). And then select $ ^4C_1 $ gaps and place both of them in the same gap in two ways (if they sit together).
So the total number of ways they could be seated is $ 3! \times ( ^4C_2 + ^4C_1\times 2 )= 84 $.

*Finding the numerator:*
Lets consider the Indian people as one unit. Now we got 5 units. So the ways to arrange them will be $ 4! $ . And the Indian couple themselves could be arranged in two ways. $ 4! \times 2 = 48$

So the final probability should be $ \frac {48}{84} $

I'm sure someone will spot my mistake.
All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to consider the four units AND the two Indian people at the round table. So in total it's as if we have $6$ objects at a round table and then we need to consider the interior arrangements of the American couples. So this is:

$$(6-1)! * (2!)^4$$

For the numerator, we have $5$ units in total now, and we need to consider all $5$ interior arrangements. So this is $$(5-1)! * (2!)^5$$

So the final probability should be $$\frac{(5-1)! * (2!)^5}{(6-1)!*(2!)^4} = \frac25 $$

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this problem can be simplified by considering combinations only. In the circle of the 4 pairs of American couples and the Indian wife, there are only 5 spaces into which the Indian husband can be placed. Hence, there are 2 instances of placing the Indian husband adjacent to his wife, as compared 3 instances of him being placed apart.

$p = 2/(2 + 3) = 2/5$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.   For the sample space, we have six objects to arrange, the four American couples and the two Indian spouses.  Each American couple can be arranged internally in $2!$ ways.  For the favorable cases, we have five objects to arrange, namely the five couples, each of which can be arranged internally in $2!$ ways.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see why order matters. For each and every arrangement of US couples, there is always a fixed number of spaces (4) to insert the Individual Indians. So, for any single US configuration, the ratio of positions where the Indians are adjacent (same space) to the total number of positions where they could be placed is 4/16. What am I missing that you are seeing?

Comment: Instead, of trying to place the members of the Indian couple in the gaps, let's seat the Indian woman first, then place the others around her.  There are five objects to arrange,  the four couples and her husband.  There are $5!$ ways to arrange the objects.  If her husband is next to her, he can be seated in two ways, on her left or right, and the remaining people can be seated in $4!$ ways, giving a probability that the members of the Indian couple are adjacent of $$\frac{2 \cdot 4!}{5!} = \frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: Ah yes, now I see it. If the US couples and the Indian wife are seated, then the India husband can be fitted into 2 of the 5 gaps to satisfy the adjacent requirement. Thanks.

Comment: I figured out how to make your original approach work.  We first seat the American couples, which creates four gaps.  The favorable cases are those in which both members of the Indian couple are placed in the same gap.  There are four ways to choose the gap and two ways to arrange the couple within that gap, giving us eight favorable cases.  There are four ways to place the Indian husband in a gap and three ways to place his wife in a different gap, giving $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ additional cases.  Thus, the probability that Indians sit together is $$\frac{8}{8 + 12} = \frac{8}{20} = \frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: Good, that is another way again. I always like the solution to make sense mathematically rather than just plugging numbers into an equation. Thanks for your patience.